# Script to create files in a template

Tags: bash, vim, function

I just wrote a function in my `~/.bashrc` that will let me create a folder for a new website with one command. The function looks like this:

```
function newsite() {
  mkcd "$*"  # mkdir and cd into it
  mkdir "js"
  mkdir "imgs"
  touch "index.html"
  touch "main.css"
  vim "index.html"
}
```

Now what I would like to do is, instead of just touching index.html and main.css I'd like to create basic template files for index.html and main.css problem is I have absolutely no idea how to do that. I don't know much about writing to files using bash commands. Typically I'd just open the files in vim and go to town but I'd like to have something already started when I get into vim...

Comment: It'd probably be easier to save your templates in some directory `site_template/`, and just do a recursive copy from the template folder to the new site folder, followed by whatever `cd` and `vim` commands you want.

Comment: @jw013 AH Yes super simple! Thank you very much :D Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Looks like @HaiVu posted an answer already, so need for me to make another :)

Comment: You're better off using a build tool like `scons` to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jw013's idea and HaiVu's answer are both correct. However for the sake of completeness for anyone who comes upon this question wanting the answer, here it is;

```
function newsite() {
  mkcd "$*"  # mkdir and cd into it
  mkdir "js"
  mkdir "imgs"
  cat > index.html <<'EOI'
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
EOI
  cat > main.css <<'EOI'
body {
 font-family: Arial;
}
EOI
  vim "index.html"
}
```

The `<<'EOI'` thing is called a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), most scripting languages have them.

Answer (score 6):

I like jw013's idea:

```
mkdir -p ~/site_template/{js,imgs}
# Creates all the files in this directory: index.html, main.css, ...
```

Now, when it's time to create a new site:

```
cp -r ~/site_template ~/my_site
```

That would be much easier. Plus, you can edit your site template files any way you like.