# Tool for creating and calling folder structure templates?

Tags: filesystems, directory, directory-structure, utilities, template

Is there a Linux utility for creating templates for directory structures, outside of the scripts packaged with a DE like Gnome or LXDE? (I run openbox and would like to avoid a DE at all costs)

There is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31343/script-to-create-files-in-a-template) post talking about template files, which I will absolutely use, and there is the [template toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) but that's more for documents and dynamic web content (although, it can be easily extended).

I'm looking for something to encompass whole directory structures as well.

Say I have a C template directory structure like so:

```
prj_?\    
    Doxyfile
    Makefile
    README
    bin\
    data\
    doc\
    include\
    src
```

Or a nodejs template structure like:

```
index.html
js/
    main.js
    models/
    views/
    collections/
    templates/
    libs/
        backbone/
        underscore/
        ...
css/
...
```

Surely there must be something available, given that folders like /skel exist... or is that yet another manually scripted section of Linux?

If this doesn't yet exist, I would love to contribute to the community by writing and maintaining a tool of this nature, or at the very least writing a vim plugin to handle such functionality (spoiler alert: doesn't exist), but that would be something to discuss on the vim exchange.

Comment: I suspect a shell script with a `mkdir -p` call is common. Unclear what the advantage over that would be; could you clarify a little what you envision?

Comment: yeh sure... I mean, calling mkdir -p for every single differing template would just be laborious and essentially repeated work. By the same token, as you mentioned, this would be a fairly common thing that many people would do hence a small tool with some config file options would be helpful. I would envision a small CL tool, with definitions for file types. I could imagine a syntax like <command> <filetype i.e. C, HTML etc> <directory>. I would add hooks functionalities for git and vim, and config files could be in yml or json.

Comment: Well, you save the `mkdir -p` line in a script file, so you don't ever have to retype it. You're basically just passing it a list of directory names, so hard to get shorter than that. Or alternatively, you have a built-out directory tree and want to duplicated it, but that's what `cp -r` does. (`/etc/skel`, BTW, at least on Debian is implemented by account creation script adduser, a perl script — it just copies the files in a rather weird way, probably it can't depend on File::Find being available). Catalyst (perl MVC framework) does have its app setup script, which does something similar...

Comment: yeh I figured as much... that's cool, just wanted to see if I was missing something obvious. I'll definitely have a dig through useradd/adduser (Arch/Debian) and see what I can make of perl. Thanks for clarifying! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mtree(1)` utility](https://man.openbsd.org/mtree) is standard on BSD systems, and I'm pretty sure it ought to be available for Linux as well somewhere.  It reads a directory hierarchy specification and compares it with what's found on disk, optionally deleting files (or updating their permissions or ownership) and creating missing directories as needed.

Its specification does not *quite* look like what you have.  The specification for an `/etc` directory, as found on an OpenBSD base system, would look like

```
/set type=dir uname=root gname=wheel mode=0755
.
    etc
        X11
            app-defaults
            ..
            twm
            ..
            xenodm
                pixmaps
                ..
            ..
            xinit
            ..
            xsm
            ..
        ..
        fonts
            conf.avail
            ..
            conf.d
            ..
        ..
    ..
```

That would be the tool for creating *empty directories* (`mtree -d -u -f spec_file` or something similar).  If you want to create something like a populated directory hierarchy from some *skeleton directory*, I would use a `tar` archive of the skeleton directory and just unpack that at the destination.

An existing skeleton directory can be copied with `pax` easily:

```
( cd -- "$skel_dir" && pax -rw -p p . "$dest_dir" )
```

Comment: Heck to the yes my dude, this is exactly what I'm looking for... you legend!!